# Can't open imported VMDK file

Tags: vmware

I downloaded a VM instance from the web and launched / modified it using  it using VMware Workstation 12 Player

I would now like to transfer this image onto an ESXi host running VMware ESXi Version 5.5.0.

I have tried copying the working directory "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64\Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64" to the ESXi datastore and have tried to import it using a couple of methods:

1. I tried browsing to the Datastore, right clicking the "Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64.vmx" file and selecting "add to inventory"
2. I tried creating a virtual machine, selecting the option to use and existing disk and pointed it at the VMDK file.

Both methods allow me to create the machine, but fail with the following error when I try to power it up.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
Module DiskEarly power on failed. 
Cannot open the disk '/vmfs/volumes/4dc219c6-2eb825c6-0119-d8d3855f4a40/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on. 
The system cannot find the file specified
VMware ESX cannot find the virtual disk "/vmfs/volumes/4dc219c6-2eb825c6-0119-d8d3855f4a40/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64/Kali-Linux-2.0.0-vm-amd64.vmdk". Verify the path is valid and try again.

I have checked and I can see the VMDK file on the Datastore.

I don't know if it of any significance, but the files on my desktop are broken down into multiple VMDK files and when I copied it to the Datastore, it turned them into one large VMDK file.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to use vmware converter to import the vm into your esxi host and/or even try an export to OVF from workstation and then an import (deploy OVF) to ESXi host.
From the error generated it looks like the original VM may still have some snapshots. Try and remove any snapshots, then take note of the disk controller and disk type of the workstation vm and check that it is supported for ESXi vm (for example IDE etc.), ESXi likes SCSI.